# A cut on the sidewall of the tire?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

I was parking on the street and I didn't pay much attention, so I hit a curb. I checked the tire and found a cut on it. Does it need to be replaced? I just bought this car and replaced the tires a few months ago.

[image]

Comment: Something odd about that tire; it shows a discontinuity just above the bottom center of the picture, the side wall molding pattern changes. That and the age cracking would make me want to replace it

Answer (score 1):

That cut is in a weak area of the sidewall, a point at which the rubber isn't particularly thick. That is sufficient to recommend replacement. Additionally, the tire is showing severe checking/cracking, likely due to age. Consider to locate the date code on the tire to determine how old it is. All signs point to a replacement soonest.